# Sublime Text 2/3: Arrow key navigation

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

In Textpad, when you press the down arrow key in a line, insert some text, and then press down again, you will stay in the same position that you were at **before** you inserted text.

Sublime Text instead jumps to the position **after** inserting text.

Is there a setting that will address this shortcoming of the Sublime Text editor?

(I am using Sublime Text 3, but I assume it's the same in version 2.)